Is it normal for the convergence curve of the simulated annealing results to look like this?
In a minimization problem I used the simulated annealing algorithm to search for an answer, my initial parameter settings were initial temperature T=100000, termination temperature Tf=1e-5, and coefficient of cooling alpha=0.98.
The algorithm can find a better solution in the time I set (although when the problem scales up to the largest scenario in my estimation, often the algorithm outputs the initial solution that I got via the greedy algorithm - because the initial solution's fitness value is the best), but I found that when I use the number of iterations of the algorithm as the x-axis, each iteration accepted fitness value as the y-axis for graphing, the curve I get is so oscillating

I have searched the convergence graphs of the results of classical simulated annealing algorithms in other papers on the Internet, and the curve will slowly reduce the amplitude of its oscillations after a certain number of iterations, and finally converge to a straight line, but this phenomenon does not appear in my algorithm.


Or, is this a normal phenomenon of this local optimization method in solving real production problems?
Finally, at the end of the iteration, I will let the algorithm return the historical optimal solution instead of the current solution, that's why I can get an optimized result.
Here is my code
# Set SA parameters
T = 1e+5
TF = 1e-5
alpha = 0.98
# Start Iteration
answer = findInitialAnswer(data)
fitness = calculateFitness(answer)
answer_best_history = answer
fitness_best_history = fitness
while T > Tf:
  for _ in range(num_iter):
    # Randomly swap the position of two elements in the answer list
    idx_from = random.sample(answer, 1)
    while True:
      idx_to = random.sample(answer, 1)
      if idx_to != idx_from:
        break
    answer_new = answer
    answer_new[idx_from], answer_new[idx_to] = answer_new[idx_to], answer_new[idx_from]
    fitness_new = calculateFitness(answer_new)
    if fitness_new < fitness:
      answer = answer_new
      fitness = fitness_new
      if fitness_new < fitness_best_history:
        answer_best_history = answer_new
        fitness_best_history = fitness_new
    else:
      p = math.exp(-1*(fitness_new - fitness)/T)
      r = random.random()
      if r > p:
        answer = answer_new
        fitness = fitness_new
  # cooling
  T = T * alpha

# end
return answer_best_history, fitness_best_history

EDIT：
I find that in order for you to find out why, I must explain the exact context of the problem.
I'm solving a production line balancing problem: a production line is used to produce a fixed type of good, the good goes through n processes, and right now I have m workstations on hand, the workstations have a limitation on the type of equipment, and the processes have a demand for the type of equipment, i.e., the processes that demand x equipment must be placed at the workstations that provide x equipment. There is no restriction on the number of processes that can be assigned to a workstation, and when two processes are placed on the same workstation, the worktime of the workstation is the sum of the two. The problem wants to have the algorithm generate an assignment and consolidation plan for the processes that will allow the production line to be the most productive.
I have set the optimization objective as minimizing the man-hours at the bottleneck station on the production line - i.e., the man-hours at the station with the largest process time among the stations.
In the code, I use an array of 0's and 1's to represent the queue of processes before merging, denoted as anwser. when anwser[i]=1 indicates that there is a workstation here, then until the next anwser[j]=1, the processes i through j during the period are stored in the workstation located at i.
To compute fitness, I traverse the array and check for the largest merged workstation, using it as the fitness value for the algorithm
EDIT2：
Although it was a bit difficult, I made three graphs upon request, where the first one has T as the y-axis and the number of cool-downs as the x-axis; the second and third one each have p and fitness_new as the y-axis and their number of generations as the x-axis, and they're scatter plots (because line plots are so bad)


Thx for any help and suggestions

Could you share some snippet of the code?

@MatheusDiógenesAndrade ok, I code my code in the end of the problem

Try to debug your algorithm/code: look at the values fitness, fitness_new and p during the search; look at the neighborhoods of the solutions to see how many improving solutions they contain etc

@fontanf Could you please explain in more detail? My neighborhood building method currently relies on simply swapping the indexes of the elements in the solution list, what exactly is fitness, I've re-edited the question and clarified it

@CangWangu, please, could you plot two graphs? One showing the T (x-axis) related to the generated p (y-axis), and another presenting T related to fitness_new?

@MatheusDiógenesAndrade,This is somewhat difficult because, as my code shows, when the algorithm determines that the current temperature is not yet at the cutoff temperature, it repeats the num_iter as-you-go swap to try to find a new neighborhood solution before it cools down once.
This also means that the number of fitness_new values will be num_iter times the number of cool downs. Then, since p will only be computed when a sub-solution is generated, the number of p's will be less than fitness_new, but certainly more than the number of cool-downs.

Thanks to @MatheusDiógenesAndrade's suggestion, I finally realized what the problem was after making a scatterplot to monitor the p trend.
In the Monte Carlo method I used, the acceptance probability p is supposed to be seen with cooling - and the pattern of change of p in my code is the same, it is the way I programmed the implementation that is the problem:
Instead of using r>p to accept the subequivalent solution, I should have done the opposite, accepting the condition when r<=p, which would have correctly implemented the meaning of Monte Carlo's method: accepting with greater probability in the initial phase, and accepting with progressively smaller probability in subsequent phases of convergence.
Now I get some normal graph like this:

However, the trend in p is still not quite normal, and I've found that even late in the iteration, there are multiple instances of very extreme values of 1 vs. 0. I should probably look for the cause again

EDIT:
I find it.
The reason that the curve for p will appear to be distributed at 1 in the middle and late iterations is that the algorithm is stuck in some local optimum, so that the new solution fitness_new obtained at each round of iterations is the same as the current solution fitness, which would result in e**(-1*(0/T))=1 and hence the curve is the way it is.
So I modify the discriminant condition to accept new solutions when they have the same fitness value as the current solution, and then I get a new curve with respect to the acceptance probability p
if fitness_new <= self.fitness: 
    self.fitness = fitness_new
    self.ans = ans_new[:]
    if fitness_new < self.fitness_best_history:
        self.fitness_best_history = fitness_new
        self.ans_best_history = ans_new[:]
else:
    p = math.exp(-1*(fitness_new - self.fitness)/T)
    r = random.random()
    if r <= p:
        self.fitness = fitness_new
        self.ans = ans_new


The curve looks much more normal this time around, but I remain concerned that the drop in acceptance probability seems too fast. It hasn't even reached half of the expected number of iterations and it's already converging to 0

Great! Concerning the supposed abnormality on $p$, maybe you should try to plot a box plot per time interval, because at the end, the existence of multiple 1s and 0s for $p$ is not really an issue, especially if the ocurrence cases are too low.

@MatheusDiógenesAndrade， I did in fact find out why this was happening and I edited the details in the answer.But I also have some concerns about whether the curve of the modified p is dropping too fast, it basically arrives near 0 before the number of iterations reaches half of the total, is this normal please?

The behaviour of $p$, as well of the fitness, may vary according to the instance attributes magnitude, for example: number of nodes, edges, vehicle weight capacity, and so on. Therefore, in order to have a preciser diagnostic, it would be interesting to track the behaviour of more instances, specially big ones. So, if possible, try to run the algorithm for maybe 3 or 4 instances, and then compare the graphics.
